Potential Silent data loss on Kafka Connect
We are running debezium v2.3.5 on cp kafka connect v7.5.0. And we detected data loss 3 times in the part month.
The sequence is the same for all 3 instances

The Debezium pod running the connector is churned.
A new pod is bootstrapped.
The connector attempts to resume from the last commit LSN.
A SocketTimeoutException occurs when connecting to the schema registry.
The system then resumes normal operation.

Based on my analysis, it appears that the issue lies within the AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java class in Kafka Connect, where messages are dropped when a SocketTimeoutException occurs.
Below are the code snippets that could be causing the issue
boolean sendRecords() {
        int processed = 0;
        recordBatch(toSend.size());
        final SourceRecordWriteCounter counter =
                toSend.size() > 0 ? new SourceRecordWriteCounter(toSend.size(), sourceTaskMetricsGroup) : null;
        for (final SourceRecord preTransformRecord : toSend) {
            retryWithToleranceOperator.sourceRecord(preTransformRecord);
            final SourceRecord record = transformationChain.apply(preTransformRecord);
            final ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> producerRecord = convertTransformedRecord(record);
            if (producerRecord == null || retryWithToleranceOperator.failed()) {
                counter.skipRecord();
                recordDropped(preTransformRecord);
                continue;
            }
.........

}


protected ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> convertTransformedRecord(SourceRecord record) {
        if (record == null) {
            return null;
        }

        RecordHeaders headers = retryWithToleranceOperator.execute(() -> convertHeaderFor(record), Stage.HEADER_CONVERTER, headerConverter.getClass());

        byte[] key = retryWithToleranceOperator.execute(() -> keyConverter.fromConnectData(record.topic(), headers, record.keySchema(), record.key()),
                Stage.KEY_CONVERTER, keyConverter.getClass());

        byte[] value = retryWithToleranceOperator.execute(() -> valueConverter.fromConnectData(record.topic(), headers, record.valueSchema(), record.value()),
                Stage.VALUE_CONVERTER, valueConverter.getClass());

        if (retryWithToleranceOperator.failed()) {
            return null;
        }

        return new ProducerRecord<>(record.topic(), record.kafkaPartition(),
                ConnectUtils.checkAndConvertTimestamp(record.timestamp()), key, value, headers);
    }

It looks like convertTransformedRecord returns a null after exhausting retries in retryWithToleranceOperator.failed(). And sendRecords() simply adds the record to recordDropped set and moves on.
Let me know if I'm missing something. Thanks!
Below are the logs
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,342] INFO Starting streaming (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,342] INFO Retrieved latest position from stored offset 'LSN{23E06/D8470B58}' (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,343] INFO Looking for WAL restart position for last commit LSN 'LSN{23E06/D8470920}' and last change LSN 'LSN{23E06/D8470B58}' (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.WalPositionLocator)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,343] INFO Initializing PgOutput logical decoder publication (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,384] INFO Obtained valid replication slot ReplicationSlot [active=false, latestFlushedLsn=LSN{23E06/D8470920}, catalogXmin=1133472740] (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,414] INFO Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,416] INFO Seeking to LSN{23E06/D8470920} on the replication slot with command SELECT pg_replication_slot_advance('<redacted>', '23E06/D8470920') (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,434] INFO Requested thread factory for connector PostgresConnector, id = cdc.<redacted> named = keep-alive (io.debezium.util.Threads)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,434] INFO Creating thread debezium-postgresconnector-cdc.<redacted>-keep-alive (io.debezium.util.Threads)

[2024-10-26 00:26:27,492] INFO Searching for WAL resume position (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,494] INFO First LSN 'LSN{23E06/D8470B58}' received (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.WalPositionLocator)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,525] INFO LSN after last stored change LSN 'LSN{23E06/D8472210}' received (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.WalPositionLocator)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,525] INFO WAL resume position 'LSN{23E06/D8472210}' discovered (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,528] INFO Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,530] INFO Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,549] INFO Initializing PgOutput logical decoder publication (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,551] INFO Seeking to LSN{23E06/D8470920} on the replication slot with command SELECT pg_replication_slot_advance('<redacted>', '23E06/D8470920') (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,564] INFO Requested thread factory for connector PostgresConnector, id = cdc.<redacted> named = keep-alive (io.debezium.util.Threads)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,564] INFO Creating thread debezium-postgresconnector-cdc.<redacted>-keep-alive (io.debezium.util.Threads)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,564] INFO Processing messages (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,566] INFO Streaming requested from LSN LSN{23E06/D8470B58}, received LSN LSN{23E06/D8470B58} identified as already processed (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.AbstractMessageDecoder)
[2024-10-26 00:26:27,621] INFO Message with LSN 'LSN{23E06/D8472210}' arrived, switching off the filtering (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.WalPositionLocator)
[2024-10-26 00:26:36,273] INFO 10.11.129.255 - - [26/Oct/2024:00:26:36 +0000] "GET /connectors/<redacted>/config HTTP/1.1" 200 2279 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0" 1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2024-10-26 00:27:27,928] ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://<schema-registry>/subjects/cdc.<redacted>.public.cdc_audit_heartbeat-key/versions?normalize=false (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:615)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:509)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:604)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:376)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:397)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1192)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1086)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1020)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1372)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1347)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:303)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:408)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:588)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:576)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:311)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerWithResponse(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:427)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerWithResponse(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:404)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.registerWithResponse(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:512)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.AbstractKafkaProtobufSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaProtobufSerializer.java:121)
    at io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter$Serializer.serialize(ProtobufConverter.java:182)
    at io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter.fromConnectData(ProtobufConverter.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$5(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:214)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:396)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:361)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-10-26 00:27:28,082] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=<redacted>-0} Committing offsets for 16 acknowledged messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2024-10-26 00:27:28,582] INFO 551 records sent during previous 00:01:01.879, last recorded offset of {server=cdc.<redacted>} partition is {transaction_id=null, lsn_proc=631149078648192, messageType=INSERT, lsn_commit=631149078648136, lsn=631149078648192, txId=1133473687, ts_usec=1729902447792485} (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask)
[2024-10-26 00:27:28,778] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=<redacted>-0} Committing offsets for 458 acknowledged messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2024-10-26 00:27:29,235] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=<redacted>-0} Committing offsets for 76 acknowledged messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2024-10-26 00:27:29,741] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=<redacted>-0} Committing offsets for 9 ac


